# Lightning Web Component custom combo-box list items not clickable

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I have custom search lookup combo box that displays as expected, but the list items are not responding to clicks and I cannot figure out why. Specifically the `onclick={predictionSelected}` on the `<div>` that encloses the contents of the `<li>` defining the iterated list items.  Something must be eating the events, but it is not clear to me what that could be.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
    <div>
        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                <div class="slds-combobox_container">
                    <div class="slds-combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                        <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right"
                            role="none">
                            <template if:false={predictionSelected}>
                                <input class="slds-input slds-combobox__input" id="combobox-id-1"
                                    aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="listbox-id-1" role="textbox" type="text"
                                    placeholder="Search..." onkeyup={handleKeyChange} value={searchTerm} />
                            </template>
                            <template if:true={predictionSelected}>
                                <span class="slds-pill slds-pill_link fullWidth slds-input slds-combobox__input">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-pill__action slds-p-left_x-small"
                                        title={selectedValue}>
                                        <lightning-icon icon-name={iconname} size="x-small"></lightning-icon>
                                        <span class="slds-pill__label slds-p-left_x-small">{selectedValue}</span>
                                    </a>
                                    <button onclick={clearSelection}
                                        class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon slds-pill__remove"
                                        title="Remove">
                                        <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close" size="small"
                                            alternative-text="Press delete or backspace to remove"></lightning-icon>
                                        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Remove</span>
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                            </template>
                        </div>
                        <template if:true={predictions}>
                            <div class="slds-combobox_container">
                                <div id="listbox-id-1" class="slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_fluid" role="listbox">
                                    <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="presentation">
                                        <template for:each={predictions} for:item="prediction">
                                            <li key={prediction.place_id} role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item" >
                                                <div class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small"
                                                    role="option" data-itemid={prediction.place_id} data-itemname={prediction.id}
                                                    onclick={predictionSelected}>
                                                        <lightning-icon icon-name={iconname} size="x-small"
                                                            data-itemid={prediction.place_id} data-itemname={prediction.id}>
                                                        </lightning-icon> 
                                                        {prediction.description}
                                                </div>
                                            </li>

                                        </template>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you share your JS code as well?

Comment: Look at [this playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/sHGhYC3sL/1/edit). I tried to build your code and the onclick event is working as expected.

Comment: Share your JS controller please, it's impossible to help you without it, it's a pretty simple task to call a function, so you have something wrong in your controller.

Comment: First, thanks all for responding, I really appreciate it.  I took a look at @Arthlete playground, so decided to throw my raw code into one and when in the playground the click handler is throwing an exception that it does not when the component is in salesforce so I assume that is the core of the problem.  Going to track that down and I will update when I know more.  Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

As the playground @Arthlete posted worked and my code throws an exception in the playground (not sure why the exception not shown in Salesforce must get caught and eaten somewhere) I looked at the exception as it was the new piece of information: `Uncaught Error: Assert Violation: Invalid event handler for event 'click' on [object:vm undefined (1)].`

So you were both right the problem was in javascript controller.  I had a property named `predictionSelected` and the click handler was named `predictionSelected`.  But as Salesforce was eating the exception, I couldn't see the core problem.  Renaming the click handler to `handlePredictionSelected` fixes the problem and now the component is behaving.

Thank you @Arthlete for the playground as that was the key to tracking this down.